# Comma separated images for .gif creation

Tags: import, image, animation, gif-format

I recently created a key frame animation using Mandelbulber 2.18-1. Each .png image was placed in a folder with known location. I then dragged all the images and dropped them into a Mathematica notebook.

The images were separated by a space only. I manually placed the images between curly braces and put a comma between each pair and assigned them to the name "images". The following code generated an animated .gif exactly as intended:

```
Export["Madelbulb.gif", images,"AnimationRepetitions" -> \[Infinity]]
```

However, I can envision a much larger project and am wondering if there is a way to import the images as a comma separated list automatically? This was 300 images. Already quite mind numbing with the commas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put all the images in a folder by themselves, then use the following code:

```
imagePaths = FileNames["path/to/images/*.png"];
images = Import /@ imagePaths;
```

Comment: That works perfectly.